# How to write MongoDB index in Node without waiting for the result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a database migration script which should create a set of indexes, but waiting for the index creation on some large collections would take a ridiculous amount of time.  Instead of waiting, my intent is to provide a small script which will allow us to observe the progress of the indexes as desired.

This is the command I am using with the Node driver (v4.12.0) to create the script:

```
const result = await collection.createIndexes([
    {
        key: { tenantId: 1, "meta.serverModifiedTime": -1 },
        name: INDEX_NAME,
        background: true
    }
], {
    writeConcern: { w: 0 },
});
```

While observing the code in debug mode with (relatively) small collections, I can see this command taking significantly longer for the largest of these collections.  This seems to suggest the command is ignoring the writeConcern and is waiting for the index creation to complete before resolving the promise.

Moreover, if I dig into the node driver internals and get the actual response from the server, the response data seems to bear out my conclusion:

```
{
  numIndexesBefore: 1,
  numIndexesAfter: 2,
  createdCollectionAutomatically: false,
  commitQuorum: "votingMembers",
  ok: 1,
  $clusterTime: {...},
}
```

I also request pending operations immediately after starting the index creation and see that no pending index operations exist:

```
const currentOps = await db.command({ currentOp: 1 });
currentOps.inprog.forEach(function(op) {
    if (op.msg && op.command) {
        if (op.command.createIndexes || op.command.reIndex || op.command.dropIndex) {
            console.log(op.msg); // never logs anything from here.
        }
    }
});
```

**How can I get mongo to respect the writeConcern and return immediately?**

(BTW - removing the `await` is not the answer, I clean up my connection by closing it and the connection will close before the operation has completed and complain -- so it will wait for the index anyway and just crash when the connection closes.)

Comment: I've answered here:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250055/answer

Comment: An interesting idea, but it didn't work. "startIndexBuild" is not a valid command unfortunately.

Comment: Shame, I've put ChatGPT into a test, it failed here 